# Accessing vars inside functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables

In the following code:

```
 var pie = [];

function makeChart() {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(
        pie);
};

var data = jQuery.getJSON('xxx', function(data) {

    pie = [{
        value: data.company_live_ads,
        color: "#F7464A"
    }, {
        value: data.total_candidates,
        color: "#46BFBD"
    }, {
        value: data.company_ads_published_3days,
        color: "#FDB45C"
    }, {
        value: data.company_apps_today,
        color: "#4D5360"
    }];

    makeChart();
});
```

The pie var is updated in the JSON function. Then the makeChart function is called. If I was to put console.log(pie) inside makeChart() it would print me the array Pie with figures. However, for some reason, it doesn't pass this var into the function that makes the chart. Moreover, if I put a var of pie inside this function with Dummy Data it generates the chart.

I think this must have something to do with the scope, but I'm a little lost. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted should be fine. What's going wrong? Are errors reported?

Comment: No errors reported, I have shown a couple of people it seems very strange as mentioned above if I put in a local array of pie with hard coded data it seems to work fine.

Comment: I should add I am using chart.js if that makes a difference that I am including a 3rd party lib

Comment: So long as that `<canvas>` element exists at the time the function is called, it should work. Is your code called from a DOMReady or onload handler, or is it in the document head?

Comment: I tried wrapping it in jQuery( "#canvas" ).load(function() and Document ready but these haven't worked either

Comment: Ok so I have noticed that if I put it on #canvas load nothing is happening but if I put in Document ready some of the script is running.. is there known issues about canvas not loading correctly ?

Comment: There's nothing special about `<canvas>` elements.  You can achieve the same effect as a "ready" handler by simply moving your code to the very end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON was delivering numbers as strings hence why hard coded values were working. Used parseInt() to change to numbers and chart generated.